# Split CSS style by color for Corner ribbon code

Tags: css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I'm trying to split the code by adding a property for the color
As a general rule, I would use a selector extension

```
.ribbon.mycolor {
   css.tag1: value_tage1;
   ...
}
```

But it does not work because part of the code is a span and I do not know how to mock it in this case.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  background: #EEE;
}

.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#F70505 0%, #8F0808 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: -21px;
}

.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}

.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}

// Edited with partial solution
.red span {
  background: linear-gradient(#F70505 0%, #8F0808 100%);
}

.red span::before {
  border-left-color: #8F0808;
  border-top-color: #8F0808;
}

.red span::after {
  border-right-color: #8F0808;
  border-top-color: #8F0808;
}

.blue span {
  background: linear-gradient(#2989d8 0%, #1e5799 100%);
}

.blue span::before {
  border-left-color: #1e5799;
  border-top-color: #1e5799;
}

.blue span::after {
  border-right-color: #1e5799;
  border-top-color: #1e5799;
}

.orange span {
  background: linear-gradient(#F79E05 0%, #8F5408 100%);
}

.orange span::before {
  border-left-color: #8F5408;
  border-top-color: #8F5408;
}

.orange span::after {
  border-right-color: #8F5408;
  border-top-color: #8F5408;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="ribbon orange"><span>PROFESIONAL</span></div>
</div>
```

Edited snippet adding code, work, but i think is not best way.

```
.red span {background: linear-gradient(#F70505 0%, #8F0808 100%);}
.red span::before {border-left-color: #8F0808; border-top-color: #8F0808;}
.red span::after {border-right-color: #8F0808; border-top-color: #8F0808;}

.blue span {background: linear-gradient(#2989d8 0%, #1e5799 100%);}
.blue span::before {border-left-color: #1e5799; border-top-color: #1e5799;}
.blue span::after {border-right-color: #1e5799; border-top-color: #1e5799;}

.orange span {background: linear-gradient(#F79E05 0%, #8F5408 100%);}
.orange span::before {border-left-color: #8F5408; border-top-color: #8F5408;}
.orange span::after {border-right-color: #8F5408; border-top-color: #8F5408;}
```

Comment: you don't know how to mock a span?  not sure what this means.  one possible approach is to tell the span that his older brother div is way more talented.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here. Could you maybe make a picture in photoshop or paint to display the wanted result?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve... can you reword the mock sentence. Are you trying to get something like `.ribbon.mycolor span`? it's unclear what you are trying to split out of your current code

Comment: I've edited my own question, but  I think is not best way, because span tags for all docment is affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for variable where you can easily change the color of your ribbon by using new classes without having to change CSS:

```css
:root {
  --color-1: #8F0808;
  --color-2: #F70505;
}

.box {
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  background: #EEE;
  display:inline-block;
}

.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--color-2) 0%, var(--color-1) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: -21px;
}

.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid var(--color-1);
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid var(--color-1);
}

.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid var(--color-1);
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid var(--color-1);
}

.orange {
  --color-1: #8F5408;
  --color-2: #F79E05;
}
.blue {
  --color-1: #1e5799;
  --color-2: #2989d8;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="ribbon"><span>PROFESIONAL</span></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="ribbon orange"><span>PROFESIONAL</span></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="ribbon blue"><span>PROFESIONAL</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No webkit browser has needed a vendor prefix in ages.

Comment: @Rob sure,  a simple copy paste of OP code :) will update

Comment: Code is from http://www.cssportal.com/css-ribbon-generator/, with  modofications, and use with Bulma. Thanks. I've deleted webkit browser and compiling sass, and test and work fine and user :root for declare color gradient.